# Adding HTML using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The jquery below leaves the time from datetime out of the brackets but not the date.

below is the jquery:

```
 $('.counter_area').html('<div class="open-ViewCustomer well well-sm"' +
                'data-toggle="modal" data-id=' + v.id +
                ' data-first=' + v.first_name +
                ' data-last='  + v.last_name +
                ' data-time='  + v.joined_at +
                ' data-note='  + v.note +
                ' data-download=' + v.attach +
                ' href="#viewCustomer" data-placement="bottom" title="View Customer Details And Options">' + v.first_name +
                ' ' + v.last_name +
                '</div>'
            );
```

this is what it produces:

```
<div class="open-ViewCustomer well well-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-id="2" data-first="joe" 
data-last="doe" data-time="2014-03-26" 18:22:50="" data-note="null" data-download="null" 
href="#viewCustomer" data-placement="bottom" title="View Customer Details And Options">joe   doe</div>
```

as you can see `data-time="2014-03-26" 18:22:50=""` should be `data-time="2014-03-26 18:22:50"`

I'm quite new to front end development, any help to solving this is appreciated.

Comment: What is the raw format of `v.joined_at`? It's probably worth escaping it somewhere along the line, if you're not already doing that. If you don't, and the string contains unescaped chars (such as `"`), most browsers will try to 'clean' your HTML for you, resulting in this problem.

Comment: the original format is datetime but i convert it to a string before returning to ajax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a space in your joined date string, so you will need the quotes around the attribute:

```
' data-time="'  + v.joined_at + '"'+
```

Comment: @ErHunt Also have a look at using `attr()` https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes e.g. `$('.counter_area').html('<div class="open-ViewCustomer well well-sm></div>).attr({"data-time": v.joined_at,  "data-last": v.last_name});`

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are stitching a string of HTML together via jQuery, then appending it to your website. This will generally give you the results that you want, but there is a better way to do this:

```
// select the counter_area div, and append() a new jQuery object
$('.counter_area').append(
    // create a new div and make it as a jQuery object
    $('<div class="open-ViewCustomer well well-sm"></div>') 
        // Set each attribute via the jQuery attr() method 
        .attr("data-toggle", "modal")
        .attr("data-id", v.id)
        .attr("data-first", v.first_name)
        .attr("data-last", v.last_name)
        .attr("data-time", v.joined_at)
        .attr("data-note", v.note)
        .attr("data-download", v.attach)
        .attr("href", "#viewCustomer")
        .attr("data-placement", "modal")
        .attr("title", "View Customer Details And Options")
        // set the text of your new div
        .text(v.first_name + " " + v.last_name)
    );
```

### Why do it this way?

If someone says that their first name is `"onload="window.location='http://example.com'`, then anyone who visits this page will be redirected from the site. This is a security risk known as [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29): people will use it to hack your website.

If you use the code that I have provided, then jQuery will clean up the names for you: the control characters (specifically the quote (`"`)) will be written in such a way that it is made safe.

jQuery will also automatically handle spaces, quotes, and any other weird characters that might appear in the date or name, so you'll have one less thing to worry about.

Comment: Good content, probably more maintainable to just call `attr` once though and pass it an object with all of the values e.g. `.attr({"data-time": v.joined_at, "data-last": v.last_name})`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quotes around your values (after the equals and after the concatenated value).
Without them, a space in your values will be interpreted as the end of your value and the begin of a new attribute.